# What are the pitfalls and performance issues of an architecture involving Redux, useContext and HOCs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, higher-order-components

I'm working on a big SAAS productivity web app. We're using `redux` for state management.

We developed some HOCs that provide read-write accesses for each of our modules. For example, the `withProject` HOC would provide data, and methods that trigger redux actions, as such:

```
{
   id,
   name,
   createTask,
   deleteTask,
   etc.
}
```

We used to have those HOCs all over the place, and decided to replace them with `useContext` instead:

- We created some `Contexts Providers` in our `react` `Layout` component, to feed all of the children components with data / methods.
- Those Contexts are fed with the data coming from HOCs.
- We now only use those `HOCs` in our `Layout` component.
- We replaced the HOCs we were using all over the place with `useContext(Context.Project)` and other `useContext` to get access to our data and methods.

## Are there some obvious pitfalls to this approach? Is this an anti-pattern?

We started implementing it as we thought it was way cleaner to useWhatever in our components, rather than wrap all our components with different HOCs.
However, sometimes we face performance issues and I reckon they come from Context that are objects (hence firing rendering over and over due to reference equality), and not primitive values.

Comment: This question is so broad, no one can guess how you implement your context providers, you should ask a specific question [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: For example, showing two implementations (as Provider and as HOC) and asking about the pitfalls then, as a side note, I think using custom hooks is a much better approach.

Comment: My suggestion is find a context in your code base that are having perf issue, and ask questions from there?
`hence firing rendering over and over due to reference equality` for these ones, you can memoize them.